# Как сохранть значение выведенное через echo в переменную?

Tags: php, wordpress, плагин

Столкнулся с одной проблемой, на первый взгляд все не просто. Предлагаю два есть две вариации вопроса

Первая из них изолированна от остального, но отражает всю суть того, что нужно получить в конечном итоге:

```
function func() {
    echo '20';
};

func();
```

Нужно сохранить то, что выводиться с помощью echo в переменную. При этом нельзя менять саму функцию, а так же нужно удалить вывод на страницу от самого echo, т.е. в итоге у нас в переменной должно находиться число 20, а на страницу ничего не должно выводиться.

Далее вторая вариация вопроса и зачем это все вообще нужно.

Есть плагин для WordPress - Advanced Custom Fields

Есть допустим три страницы, на каждой из них нужно выводить разные посты, при этом эти страницы пользователь сам может создавать. Я придумал такую схему:

1. Создать метку
2. Через custom fields при создании страницы передавать название метки в код
3. Генерировать посты с учетом полученной метки

Таким образом юзер может создавать страницу и генерировать на ней новые посты.

Но беда в том, что плагин не возвращает значение, которое было введено юзером в поле, а просто выводит через echo под капотом как я понял. Моих познаний в PHP не достаточно чтобы исправлять что-то под капотом. Есть какие-нибудь варианты по поводу решения?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.ob-get-contents.php на первый вопрос найдете ответ здесь.

Comment: @Arendach, узнать бы еще как удалить со страницы то, что выводиться и было бы идеально)

Comment: Вам дали ссылку на документацию. Посмотрите также ближайшие функции перехвата вывода `ob-start` и т.д. С их помощью вы решите свою задачу

Comment: то что находится между ob_start(); и ob_end_clean(); на экран не выводится

Comment: @Arendach, напишите ответ, я приму

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для ваших целей надо использовать буферизацию вывода, пример:

```
<?php
ob_start();
echo "Привет ";
$out1 = ob_get_contents();
echo "Мир";
$out2 = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
var_dump($out1, $out2);
```

Все что между `ob_start();` и `ob_end_clean();` не выводится на экран а перехватить можно так `$out = ob_get_contents();`

Подробнее [ob_get_contents()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.ob-get-contents.php)

Подробнее [Функции контроля вывода](http://php.net/manual/ru/ref.outcontrol.php)